# Swapping a div source if DeviceOrientation is between two values

Tags: javascript, ios, html

trying to swap a static image for an animated image when a mobile device is held up to the sky. As you can see in the code below I'm trying to find out when the beta value is in the 'up' position, but it's not working. Any help would be much appreciated - THANKS:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <img id="ball" width="640" height="960" src="ball.png" /> 
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", swapImg); 
function swapImg(evt) { 
    var directions = document.getElementById("ball"); 
    if (evt.beta > 100 || evt.beta < 180) { 
        ball.src = "ball.gif"; 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a nonexistent variable `ball` when setting the src

Instead you should change

`ball.src = "ball.gif";`

to

`directions.src = "ball.gif";`

Comment: Sorry should have pasted more of code, the 'ball' div is in the body:<div class="container">
      <img id="ball" width="640" height="960" src="ball.png" />
  </div>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", swapImg);
  function swapImg(evt) {
  var directions = document.getElementById("ball");
                 if (evt.beta > 100 || evt.beta < 180) {
                    ball.src = "ball.gif";    
                }
}
 
  </script>

Comment: Have You tried debugging in the javascript debugger? Will You get into the if-clause?